# Centered the Portfolio title on Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress

Sorry before, I wanna ask how to centered this portfolio title:
here is the link http://f.coupleshops.com/pastries/

It's shown up the title on left side on every bottom of the image. I want to centered it. At where I should edit the css file?
Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add text-align: center to

```
h3, h3 a {
color: #2B2B2B;
font-family: 'Georgia',sans-serif;
font-size: 18px;
margin: 20px 0 13px;
text-align: center;
}
```

If you don't want all the h3 links to be affected add instead:

```
.portfolio_t2_text_holder h3, .portfolio_t2_text_holder h3 a { text-align: center; }
```

To center your price add:

```
.portfolio_t2_text_holder p { text-align: center; }
```

Comment: you are great, and now how to center the price? I've added some excerpt just now. any help?

Comment: last question, the original template of the portfolio page is this http://demo.qodeinteractive.com/lounge/portfolio-3-columns-text/ and the distance of each image is too close, I want it to become like this http://www.ladym.com/ so the distance of every image isn't too close.

Comment: You'll have to edit .portfolio_holder_v3 article and .portfolio_holder article. In the first class you can play with the width (in the demo width: 330px;). In the second class you can play with the margins (margin: 0 5px 5px 0; in your demo). Let's say you edit the width to 300px, then edit the margin to margin: 0 35px 5px 0;

Answer (score 0):

use `text-align: center;` for your `h3` tag